Create 2D representative visualisation clusters from 786D clusters
I have about 60'000 vector embedding of size 786. They divide up neatly into about 10 clusters. I have used K-Means to find the clusters. Now I would like to visualize them. The vectors should be color coded and arranged in discrete clusters. I've tried to use PCA to reduce the 786D Visualizations to 2D, but that results in a distribution where the elements are essentially randomly distributed and there are no distinct clusters.
How do I 2D visualize distinct 786D clusters?

A standard approach is multidimensional scaling (MDS), but I don't think this respects clustering... how do you know your clustering divides up so neatly? It may very well be that there is no "useful" lower dimensional representation that keeps your higher-dimensional clustering intact.

Because they are text vector embedding and the clusters make logical sense. i just need to create a 2d representation
